# Error configuring Oracle datastore in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, oracle-spatial

I want to configure an Oracle datastore in Geoserver so I copied gt2-oracle-spatial-2.3.1.jar and ojdbc14.jar into GeoServer webapp (in WEB-IF/lib folder); then I restarted and try to create new data store; I found " Oracle NG - Oracle Database" but when I click on Save I have this error in the log:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.data.DataStoreFactorySpi$Param
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:366)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
        ... 102 more
```

Where can I find the JAR file for this file?

Comment: You are doing installation right as far as I can see. There is no need to have any other jars than those included in the oracle-plugin. Plugin must be of the same version than GeoServer. Version 2.3.1 for sure works with Oracle but do you have a special reason to use just that? V. 2.3.1 which is no more maintained and if possible I recommend you to start directly with 2.6-RC1 or 2.6 nightly or at least 2.5.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look go to the Geoserver download page http://geoserver.org/download/. There, select the version of Geoserver you are using. At the bottom of the page, you will see the extensions. Listed under **Vector formats**, you will find the Oracle one. Download the zip file, it contains the dependencies you need to copy to WEB-INF/lib dir, including the appropriate Geotools oracle plugin.